# obtain input from user in Shiny and use to manipulate ggplot

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server, shiny-reactivity

I am building a simple Shiny application.
Basically, I have a set of questions (Q1-Q20), answered by different workers. Each question is likert scale from 1 to 5.

My goal is: Create a bar chart to show how many choose 1 , 2, 3, 4, 5 etc
Print a statement showing the mean and SD
For example, I want to know, among doctors, what was the mean for Q9?

I know where is the error in my code, but I don't know how to fix it
I want the x-axis in my chart in ggplot to be from this input:

`selectInput("q", "Choose a question", choices = c("Q9", "Q11", "Q13" , "Q15" , "Q17", "Q19"))`

I know using `ggplot(input$) + geom_bar()` wouldn't work.

The second error in my code is calculating the mean is this line:
`x1 <- (mean(input$q, na.rm = T))`

I want to calculate the mean from the user input, but I know I shouldn't be using `input$q`

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("course takers"),
  sidebarPanel(
    selectInput("profession", "Choose a profession", choices = unique(data$Current.Professional.Status)),
    selectInput("q", "Choose a question", choices = c("Q9", "Q11", "Q13" , "Q15" , "Q17", "Q19")),
    dateRangeInput("dates", "Choose a date range:",
                   start = "2022-01-01",
                   end = "2023-01-01"
    ),
    actionButton("calc", "Calculate Mean and SD"),
    textOutput("text")
  ),

  mainPanel(
      tabPanel("Plot", plotOutput("shapes"))
    )
  )
)


server <- function(input, output) {
  graph <- eventReactive(input$calc,
                             {
                               data %>%
                                 filter(
                                   Current.Professional.Status == input$profession,
                                   Date >= as.Date(input$dates[1]),
                                   Date <= as.Date(input$dates[2])
                                 ) 
                               
                             }
                             )
  mean_calc <- eventReactive(input$calc,
                             {
                            ** x1 <- (mean(input$q, na.rm = T))
                             x2 <- (sd(input$q , na.rm = T))**
                             print(paste("Mean = " ,round(x1, digits = 2),
                                         "SD = ", round(x2, digits = 2)))
                         }
  )
  
  output$shapes <- renderPlot({
    graph() %>% 
**    ggplot(aes(input$q)) +**
      geom_bar(width = .9) 
  })
  
  output$text <- renderText({
   mean_calc()
  })
  

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, please, in order to improve the chances of getting help, make sure that the code is reproducible in any machine. For example we are missing the contents of `data` object. You can use `dput(data)` function to create an easy to copy output in your console and be a able to share it with others.

Comment: `input$q` is a character string containing the column name. To compute the mean or sd of the selectd column use `mean(data[[input$q]])` and in your ggplot2 code use the `.data` pronoun, i.e. do `aes(.data[[input$q]])`.

Comment: @stefan it worked! Thank you! Can you explain to me the idea behind it? Thanks!

Comment: It's nothing fancy. Let's say your `data` is equal to `mtcars`and the name of the selected column is `"mpg"`, i.e. `input$q <- "mpg"`. Then using `mean(input$q)` is equal to `mean("mpg")` which makes on sense. Instead you want `mean(mtcars[["mpg"]])` i.e. `mean(data[[input$q]])`. Similarly for your ggplot2 code. Here you are doing `aes("mpg")` but instead you want `aes(mpg)`. And that's exactly what the `.data` pronoun does. For more on on the latter in the context of shiny and ggplot2 see e.g. https://mastering-shiny.org/action-tidy.html#example-ggplot2